# What is Affiliate Member in Cricket?

Tags: cricket, terminology, icc

What is Affiliate Member in Cricket? What criteria do they have to maintain? How can they considered as a [Associate Member](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3399/540)?

Comment: I have asked different questions since both questions are able to be separated and also we need [more activities](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/134/540). :)

Comment: We need more cricket activity? http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/430/the-cricket-questions-here-are-pretty-good

Comment: @edmastermind29: Yeah. But something is better than nothing. :)

Comment: True. Thanks for providing content. I had updated the statistics for the link you had provided, and we can see an upward trend in participation and activity. We are headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [icc-cricket.com](http://www.icc-cricket.com/about/96/icc-members/overview):

> #### Affiliate Members:
>
> Affiliate Members are the governing bodies for cricket of a country recognised by ICC, or countries associated for cricket purposes, or a geographical area **(which is not part of one of those already constituted as a Full Member or Associate Member) where the ICC recognises that cricket is played in accordance with the Laws of Cricket** (59 Members).

An affiliate member must maintain the following criteria along with other administration requirements of the national governing body:

- Have a minimum of 8 senior teams and 4 junior teams playing in a structured competitions
- Must have access to at least 2 cricket grounds
- Must be capable of raising in excess of $2,500 each year in income from sources other than the ICC

In order for an affiliate member to be considered for becoming to an associate member the national governing body must demonstrate that it has met the criteria for associate membership and must have also met the following playing standards within the last three years:

- Competed in all relevant Global or Regional ICC international cricket competition for past 3 years
- Ranked 1st, 2nd or 3rd highest affiliate in the region and
- Have achieved *one* of the following:

  - 2 wins against any associate nation in 50 over matches
  - Twice been highly competitive against one of the top 20 associate nations in 50 over matches
  - Once beaten an associate member and once been competitive against one of the top 20 associates in 50 over matches
  - 3 wins against any associate nation in 20 over matches
  - 3 times been highly competitive against one of the top 20 associate nations in 20 over matches
  - Twice beaten an associate member and once been highly competitive against one of the top 20 associates in 20 over matches
  - Once beaten an associate member and twice been highly competitive against one of the top 20 associates in 20 over matches
  - 3 results in ICC global or regional events with results that include any mix of wins against associate members and/or highly competitive results against one of the top 20 associate members from 50 over and/or 20 over matches

Here is the list of [ICC Member Countries 2013/2014 <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/51d02747e966a-ICC%20Member%20Countries%202013-2014.pdf)

---

Footnotes:
<sub>**A. Highly competitive (50 over)** = lost by 2 wickets or less, lost by 30 runs or less, or official tournament/match referee and/or umpires joint assessment, in writing, 
that match was well and truly in the balance with 10 overs or less remaining</sub> 
 <sub>**B. Highly competitive (20 over)** = lost by 2 wickets or less, lost by 15 runs or less, or official tournament/match referee and/or umpires joint assessment, in writing, 
that match was well and truly in the balance with 4 overs or less remaining</sub> 
<sub>**Source**: 1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Cricket_Council_members) 2. [ICC Associate Membership Criteria & Guidelines (PDF)](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_4AB60894B0CC0DED2CA2699734E48586_1343127522373_532.pdf)</sub>