# What is the minimum age to play under 19, under 16 and under 14 cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

We'd a [discussion](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-the-age-restrictions-are-followed-by-icc-for-the-under-19-cricket) about maximum age for playing under 19 cricket.

What is the minimum age to play under 19, under 16 and under 14 cricket?

Answer (score 1):

In the uk, we have requirements that players dont play open age cricket before they are 13 unless explicit permission is given by specalist expert coaches, due to ability.

In general it would be for the coach to decide whether a player had the ability and capability to safely play at a higher age group.  Certainly I have seen 14 year olds playing in both u16 and u19 cricket.

Answer (score 0):

In India we don’t have any restrictions for not allowing the player play in U19,U16 or U13 due to his/her younger age.

If he/she has the required skill set they can play at the Under-19 level at a very young age of 13 or even 12 years as the present Indian opener **Smrithi mandhana** did for the local under 19 team

> She represented for Under 16 when she was Nine and Under 19 when she
> was 12 years old respectively [Espn Sports](https://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/15870362/smriti-mandhana-journey-following-brother-practice-becoming-pivotal-india-batsman)