# age cut off date for cwc u19

Tags: cricket

For the next U19 CWC happening in bangladesh 2016.

What is the age cut off for full icc member teams?

What is the age cut off for associate icc member teams?

Comment: Related [How the age restrictions are followed by ICC for the under 19 cricket?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-the-age-restrictions-are-followed-by-icc-for-the-under-19-cricket)

Answer (score 2):

To compete in the ICC U19 CWC Players from Full Member countries must be
under the age of 19 on the 1st of September before the event takes place and
Players from Associate or Affiliate Member countries must be under the age of 20
on **1st of September** before the event takes place. (For the avoidance of doubt
this means that at midnight (in the country of birth) at the changeover from the
**31st August to the 1st of September** immediately before the event, players from 
Full Member countries must be under the age of 19 and players from Associate
and Affiliate Member countries must be under the age of 20. If Members are
in any further doubt as to the eligibility of a player they should contact ICC
offices as fielding an ineligible player is a serious offence.)

[Source](http://www.africacricket.org/pdf's/32_qualification_rules_u19_age_determination_policy.pdf)